# getObject(index, Long) return 0 for null

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

MySql jdbc:

```
resultSet.getInt(index)
```

return 0 for NULL since its return type is int, not java.lang.Integer. But

```
resultSet.getObject(index, java.lang.Long)
```

return 0 for null. It should return NULL. right? Check the column type of
the result set, the column type is java.lang.Long. It should return null, but returns 0 for null.

### UPDATE

Checked Oracle 11g: it returns null as expected.

Comment: Is your question "should it?", or is your question "it think it should, but it doesn't. What is going on?")

Comment: For getObject(...), it should return null, but returns 0.

Comment: If you're using the latest MySQL Connector/J and this still happens, then I suggest that you file a bug with MySQL.

Comment: Workaroundfor Optional: Optional.ofNullable(rs.getString("index")).map(Long::valueOf);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the JDBC 4.3 Specification:

> When the column value in the database is SQL `NULL`, it may be
>   returned to the Java application as `null`, `0`, or `false`, depending
>   on the type of the column value. Column values that map to Java
>   `Object` types are returned as a Java `null`; those that map to
>   numeric types are returned as `0`; those that map to a Java `boolean`
>   are returned as `false`. Therefore, it may be necessary to call the
>   `wasNull` method to determine whether the last value retrieved was a
>   SQL `NULL`.

Unfortunately the wording is vague, which can be interpreted to mean that `getObject` may return `0` for `NULL` if it is a numeric type, but that is not the intention.

The JDBC 1.20 specification is a lot clearer on this:

> When you read a SQL “NULL” using one of the ResultSet.getXXX methods,
>   you will receive:
>
> - A Java “null” value for those getXXX methods that return Java objects.
> - A zero value for getByte, getShort, getInt, getLong, getFloat, and getDouble
> - A false value for getBoolean.

In other words, `getObject` should return `null` for integer columns with a `NULL` value.

This is further supported by the documentation of `getObject(int/String)` (which also applies for `getObject(int/String, Class)`:

> If the value is an SQL `NULL`, the driver returns a Java `null`.

Comment: So it is a bug of Mysql JDBC? It seems that Mysql implementation of getObject(..) simply delegates it to getXXX() for specific types.

Comment: @Sunnyday Yes, it is a bug.

Comment: What is SQL null value converted to if java type is primitive type "char"?

Comment: @Sunnyday There is no support for primitive type char in JDBC. A SQL  `CHAR(1)` is just a string.